# Getting not full $_POST array after form submission

Tags: php, http-post

On one HTML form I have over 200 hidden input fields. After form is submited I only get 99 hidden input values via $_POST.

Configured .htaccess file:

```
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
```

also checked if those actualy are set with ini_get().

What could be the problem? My last guess would be to ask my hosting providers to help / modify php.ini file, but unfortunately they don't answers support on weekends.

Comment: already checked: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into php.ini `max_input_vars`. If you never touched it, you should be fine though.

See:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

All you would do to implement a higher number is create a php.ini file at your root directory, if it's not already there. Find `max_input_vars` or write it on a new line of its own. `max_input_vars = 1000;` is the default.

Make sure you also have a `name` attribute in all of your button and input HTML tag types that you want PHP to recognize, like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='someName' />
<button type='button' name='someButton'>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if you are missing any Name attributes to your input elements.

```
<input type="text" name="NECESSARY_NAME" value="value" />
```

And also check your max_input_vars in php.ini